# How to exclude variables from Doxygen output?

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to get some XML documentation from Doxygen that includes the member functions and EXCLUDES the member variables.

Is it possible to do that? From the doc I could not find much...

Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

You could enter each variable name in the EXCLUDE_SYMBOL option.  How many different variable names are there? Unless you created a similar pattern in each variable name ie.

> > Vehicle varCar, varScooter;

and then

> > EXCLUDE_SYMBOL = var*

within your config file. Just ensure no method or class name will match your pattern.  I haven't come across an elegant solution for this problem though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to document everything that is in the public interface of your classes and skip all implementation details. If that's the case, you can use `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO`.

Comment: I am afraid I have to document all member functions (public, protected and private, commented and not), and exclude all member variables...

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C, it can be useful to declare ivars in the header (so that they can be used directly in categories or subclasses).

However, to get Doxygen to skip these, add the following:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = SomeType \
AnotherType \   
_*
```

. . this depends on using the modern standard of naming ivars with a leading underscore character.